# Other functions no longer work after using SearchView in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, searchview

I have a *SearchView* in my application that searches through notes in my *RecyclerView* (I am using Room Database to store the notes).

But after using the *SearchView* my other functions no longer work unless I restart the application.

These are the functions that no longer work after using the *SearchView* such as Adding note, Editing existing note, Deleting note and Pinning/Unpinning note.

This code is inside onCreate fucntion of MainActivity:

```
searchView_home = findViewById(R.id.searchView_home);

searchView_home.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                filter(newText);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

This code is outside of onCreate function of MainActivity:

```
private void filter(String newText) {
        List<Notes> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Notes singleNote: notes){
            if (singleNote.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(newText.toLowerCase())
                    || singleNote.getNotes().toLowerCase().contains(newText.toLowerCase())){
                filteredList.add(singleNote);
            }
        }
        notesListAdapter.filterList(filteredList);
    }
```

This code is inside onBindViewHolder of my NotesListAdapter class:

```
public void filterList(List<Notes> filteredList){
        list = filteredList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

And this is the Notes model class itself:

```
@Entity(tableName = "notes")
public class Notes implements Serializable {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    int ID = 0;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "title")
    String title ="";

    @ColumnInfo(name = "notes")
    String notes = "";

    @ColumnInfo(name = "date")
    String date = "";

    @ColumnInfo(name = "pinned")
    boolean pinned = false;

    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(int ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getNotes() {
        return notes;
    }

    public void setNotes(String notes) {
        this.notes = notes;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public boolean isPinned() {
        return pinned;
    }

    public void setPinned(boolean pinned) {
        this.pinned = pinned;
    }
}
```

Comment: What function didn't work?

Comment: When you use search you are modifying list in adapter, not database. You should use RecyclerView just to present database information.

Comment: how to do that? i am new to android studio, i was just following a youtube tutorial to make this note app

Comment: Watch tutorials about modifying room database data, or read documentation. Just rewriting code from tutorial not really good way to learn coding.

Comment: You should use DAO methods to change database information. Then transfer list from database in adapter via `LiveData`.

Comment: But I don't wanna modify the database either, I just want the search view to show what's on the recycler view

Comment: Are you sure that functions don't working? Maybe recycler view not updating?

Comment: yes other functions no longer work when i use the search bar, but only the search bar works and shows the item that i am searching for...